# Building a simple randomizer which includes a dot, an underscore, the letter A and the letter B

Tags: javascript, random

Basically, I want to build a randomizer that can produce an output with following possible combinations:

```
.
. .
. . .
_
_ _
_ _ _
. _
_ .
. . _
_ . .
. _ _
_ _ .
_ . _
. _ .
```

and finally, preppend the letter A and B randomly at the beginning.

e.g.:

```
A . _
B _ _
A . . _
A _ .
B . _ _
A .

etc.
```

Any ideas of how to accomplish this with JavaScript?

Comment: You don't need jQuery to do this. Plain JavaScript will do the job.

Comment: @Diodeus Oh yeah, I think you are right. I modified the question.

Comment: Yes: put sequences in array and use `Math.random` with array's `.length` to retrieve it. Do "A"/"B" in either same way or with simple `?`. This is kind of really just way too basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another way: http://jsfiddle.net/8AHaw/

```
function makeid() {
    var text = "";
    var possibleChars = "._";
    var possibleLetters = "AB";

    text += possibleLetters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleLetters.length));
    for( var i=0; i < Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)+1; i++ )
        text += " " + possibleChars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleChars.length));

    return text;
}

for (var i=0; i < 20; i++)
    $("body").append("<div>" + makeid() + "</div>");
```

Adapted from [Generate random string/characters in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-a-string-of-5-random-characters-in-javascript)

Comment: Sorry, one last thing; how do I add spaces between each character, like in my example above?

Comment: @alexchenco Add `" " +` before `possibleChars.charAt(` http://jsfiddle.net/8AHaw/1/

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = [
    ".",
    ". .",
    ". . .",
    "_",
    "_ _",
    "_ _ _",
    ". _",
    "_ .",
    ". . _",
    "_ . .",
    ". _ _",
    "_ _ .",
    "_ . _",
    ". _ ."
    ],

    b = ["A ", "B "];



    function getRandom() {
        return b[Math.random()*b.length|0] + a[Math.random()*a.length|0];
    }

    getRandom(); //"A ."
    getRandom(); //"A _ _ _"
    getRandom(); //"B . _ _"
```

With a loop:

```
var l = 20;
while(l--) console.log( getRandom() );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess the best thing to do is to create a loop so that the result can be go until a certain number.

Comment: @alexchenco I have added a loop

Comment: Thanks a lot! Not sure which answer to choose. I guess I'll wait until people vote.